# How do you kill the ninja bear?

Tags: triple-town

In *Triple Town*, there is a bear who looks somewhat like it's dressed up as a ninja. It jumps from open space to open space on each turn. Is there a way to trap the bear to kill it like the other bears, or any other way to get rid of it?

Comment: if this is anything like the kindle version, you should have a kill 1 target item (in the kindle version it was a bomb), and its the only way to get rid of one.

Comment: @yx Haven't come across a bomb yet, but there is an Imperial Bot in the iOS version which removes/kills one item at a time. I'll give that a shot.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to everything I have read (because I was wondering the same thing), the only way to kill ninja bears is to use an Imperial Bot on them.

Comment: Confirmed this does work. Not seeing that there would be any other way, since trapping doesn't work on them.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to downvote, but this is incorrect as [this answers details how you can kill them by filling the board](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/49521/75292).

Answer (score 6):

You can also kill it by filling every other space.

Comment: Not very helpful at that point, but you are right, just tried it out.

Comment: This is actually helpful if you have a chest on the board.  Purposefully don't open the chest and when you run out of space the ninjas will turn into gravestones (but you'll still be able to move).  Though at that point you might be boned anyways...

Comment: It's also useful if you have a lot of bears on the map also. I've had it so about twelve bears and two ninja all became a single cathedral. Having said that, killing with an imperial bot is usually a better plan.

Answer (score 0):

My strategy is to hit undo every time a ninja bear tile pops up (and before I have placed it).  Sure, it costs 75 points, but that's a lot cheaper than buying an imperial bot.  After you hit undo you just go back and do whatever action you just did and then you will get a new random tile -- hopefully not another ninja bear.

Comment: That does not seem to work on the Android version at least, I got a ninja again after undoing.

Answer (score -1):

With som luck once run out of space thouse ninjas will become gravestones in correct places to get you churches and so keep playing